# Searching for reliable Swift code to perform IOS background fetch

Tags: swift, background, fetch

I found various posts on net that refer to this link

http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/

as a good reference for a well working background fetch. Unfortunately it is in Objective C which I am not able to read. Would anybody have similar reference / tutorial / example code in swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a Swift version here:

https://github.com/NSMohamedElalfy/BackgroundFetchDemo.git